# Probability of putting $k$- biggest numbers in same urn.

Tags: probability, statistics

Given 2 Urns and $n$ numbers.Each number is put with equal probablitiy in first urn or in second urn. Find Probability that the $k$- largest numbers are in first urn.

What i tried is: There are $k$ biggest elements. For every number it has $1/2 $ probability to go in first urn. So for the k biggest we have $(1/2)^k$ probability for $k$ biggest items to be in first urn. Is my assumption correct ? Can I please get some insights on what is wrong with my thinking ?

Comment: Suppose all numbers are independently assigned to 2 Urns. Then the probability of a specific number (in this case $k$-biggest number) is irrelevant to the other numbers. Thus the probability of the $k$-th biggest numbers to be in the first urn would be 1/2.

Comment: I think you misunderstood @induction601. I think OP means find the probability that the $k$ biggest numbers are all in the first urn (i.e. the biggest, the second biggest,..., the k-th biggest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning seems correct.

The probability that the biggest number is in the first urn is $\frac{1}{2}$, and independently, the probability that the second biggest number is in the first urn is $\frac{1}{2}$. Carrying on on until we reach the $k$-th biggest number, we get a probability of $\frac{1}{2}^k$

This is analogous to finding the probability that the first $k$ coin tosses are all heads.

To find the probability that the $k$ biggest numbers are in either urn, you would just take $2$ times the previous result, since these are mutually exclusive, giving $2\cdot\frac{1}{2}^k = \frac{1}{2}^{k-1}$

This is analogous to find the probability that the first $k$ coin tosses are all heads or all tails.

Comment: How could i extend this to find probability that k biggest are in either urn ? Thank you

Comment: So they are all in either the first or second urn?

Comment: Yes so they are all in either the first or second urn.